# How to read $\mathbf{x}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: soft-question

How it should be read? $\mathbf{x}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$

A value x mapped over the real field, should it be read like this?

Comment: If the notation is being used in the standard manner, $x$ is a real valued function defined over the reals

Comment: @FShrike $x$ was bold representing vector.. (Used x for position in physics

Comment: The boldface font is `\mathbf{}` or `\bf`. If that is not what your edit intended, please correct me

Comment: I would say that x is a function, not a "value", from R to R.  That is, it takes a real number input and returns a real number.

Answer (score 3):

Since (from your comment) $\mathbf{x}$ is the   function that represents the position of a particle on a line, the mathematical formalism says simply that it's a real valued function of a real variable. The domain is time. If you wanted to refer to the independent variable by name you might write $\mathbf{x}(t)$.

Mathematicians would probably not call that function $\mathbf{x}$, nor call it a "value". I don't think a physicist would either.

Answer (score 3):

It is nothing more than a function. In the context of you comment on your post, it could be interpreted as the position of a particle with respect to time, i.e. you could say that at time $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the particle is at position $\mathbf{x}(t)\in\mathbb{R}$. This is merely an interpretation, however, and it is important to realize that mathematically, there is **nothing** different between writing $\mathbf{x}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, which you would undoubtedly recognize as a function. Indeed what you interpret the function as physically is up to you, as you use mathematics to model a physical system, but mathematically that does not matter.